# On ?id=1 load page

Tags: php, html, load

I'm doing a e-commerce website and I'm trying to load a page when url is ?id=1 . I've looked for  many things but couldn't find  anything. Here  is my code:

```
if(isset($_GET['id=1'])) {
file_get_contents("pages/ev.html"); else { echo "please fullfill url";}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) and $_GET['id'] == 1) {
include("pages/ev.html");
} else {
echo "please fulfil URL";
}
```

**(Edited)**

Comment: excuse me? i didn't understand :p

Comment: Change (isset($_GET['id=1'])) to the code I put above.

Comment: Thanks so much. How can I load a html page when url is  example.com/index?id=1  ?

Comment: You're also missing echo in echo file_get_contents... though I'd use the include function instead.

Comment: Thank you so much!!